# downgrade MariaDB 10.4 to MariaDB 10.1 on centos7

Tags: centos

how downgrade  MariaDB 10.4 to MariaDB 10.1

1- i create file /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

2 -

```
service mysql stop 
yum remove MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

3-

```
yum clean all
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client net-snmp perl-DBD-MySQL -y
yum update -y
```

i have this error msg

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/garbd from install of galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package galera-4-26.4.2-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Error Summary

so how to uninstall galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64

my system centos7

Comment: Have you tried to run `yum downgrade galera-25......` command?  Or `yum downgrade MariaDB-server`  ?

Comment: i rebuilding my server  thanks for replay, no i am not tried

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal while running as root,I uninstalled galera with the below

```
yum remove galera*
```

If your MariaDB install needs galera it will install the galera version required by your MariaDB installation.

That's what uninstalled it from my CentOS 7.